# How to truncate a string using str.format in Python?

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

How to truncate a string using [`str.format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format) in Python? Is it even possible?

There is a `width` parameter mentioned in the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

```
format_spec ::=  [[fill]align][sign][#][0][width][,][.precision][type]
...
width       ::=  integer
...
```

But specifying it apparently only works for padding, not truncating:

```
>>> '{:5}'.format('aaa')
'aaa  '
>>> '{:5}'.format('aaabbbccc')
'aaabbbccc'
```

So it's more a minimal width than width really.

I know I can slice strings, but the data I process here is completely dynamic, including the format string and the args that go in. I cannot just go and explicitly slice one.

Answer (score 112, accepted):

Use `.precision` instead:

```
>>> '{:5.5}'.format('aaabbbccc')
'aaabb'
```

According to the documentation of the [Format Specification Mini-Language](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language):

> The *precision* is a decimal number indicating how many digits should be displayed after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with `'f'` and `'F'`, or before and after the decimal point for a floating point value formatted with `'g'` or `'G'`. **For non-number types the field indicates the maximum field size - in other words, how many characters will be used from the field content.** The *precision* is not allowed for integer values.

Comment: Ah, somehow I missed that. It does the trick, thank you! Accept incoming.

Comment: Is there a builtin for showing a truncation character as well? Like an ellipsis suffix when the data is truncated like so?

Comment: Don't forget to give a `width` **and** a `precision`: `{:5.5}`. This guarantees that the output will always be 5 characters which is probably what OP wanted.

Comment: @falsetru : Would you be willing to add Harvey's suggestion to your answer?

Comment: @NealGokli, added.

Comment: Is it possible to truncate the beginning of the string instead of the end?

Comment: @HendrikWiese, Yes, it's possible. `string_object[-5:]`

Comment: @falsetru Not sure if you're just kidding or answering out of context. I meant truncating the beginning of a string **inside string formatting**, of course.

Comment: @HendrikWiese, AFAIK, there's no such thing in formatting string.

Comment: This doesn't work if input is not a string though, e.g. is an integer.

Comment: You can make it work for non-strings by forcing them to stringify with `!s`: e.g. `f'{123456789!s:5.5s}'` `=>` `'12345'`

Answer (score 10):

you may truncate by the precision parameter alone:

```
>>> '{:.1}'.format('aaabbbccc')
'a'
```

the size parameter is setting the padded size:

```
>>> '{:3}'.format('ab')
' ab'
```

alex