# How to truncate and pad in python3 using just str.format?

Tags: python, string, python-3.x

I would like to do this:

```
'{pathname:>90}'.format(pathname='abcde')[-2:]
```

using string formatting instead of array indexing.
So the result would be 'de'
or in the case of pathname='e' the result would be ' e' with a space before e. If the index would be [2:] this question would be answered by [How to truncate a string using str.format in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076297)

I need this in the following example:

```
import logging
import sys
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO,style='{',format='{pathname:>90}{lineno:4d}{msg}')
logging.info('k')
```

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre No I want to truncate the beginning of the string.

Comment: yes, but your first version didn't take that into account. Retracted close vote & upvoted.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Padding at the beginning works with :>90. But I could not find syntax for trimming the beginning of the string.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisFabre Yes I did forget the minus. Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The precision trick (using a precision format) doesn't work. Only works to truncate the end of the string.

a workaround would be to slice the string *before* passing it to `str.format`:

```
>>> '{pathname:>2}'.format(pathname='abcde'[-2:])
'de'
>>> '{pathname:>2}'.format(pathname='e'[-2:])
' e'
```

since you cannot control the arguments passed to `format`, you could create a subclass of `str` and redefine format so when it meets `pathname` in the keyword arguments it truncates, then calls original `str.format` method.

Small self-contained example:

```
class TruncatePathnameStr(str):
    def format(self,*args,**kwargs):
        if "pathname" in kwargs:
            # truncate
            kwargs["pathname"] = kwargs["pathname"][-2:]
        return str.format(self,*args,**kwargs)

s = TruncatePathnameStr('##{pathname:>4}##')

print(s.format(pathname='abcde'))
```

that prints:

```
##  de##
```

use it in your real-life example:

```
logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO,style='{',
                    format=TruncatePathnameStr('{pathname:>90}{lineno:4d}{msg}'))
```

Comment: I am not sure this works in the logging example? Added the example in the question. Otherwise I would accept this question as a good workaround

Comment: Probably would work, if I could figure out the name of the logging dictionary and pass it to the .format() method. Any ideas?

Comment: eg this doesn't work: `logging.basicConfig(stream=sys.stdout, level=logging.INFO,style='{',format='{pathname:>90}'[-10:]+'{lineno:4d}{msg}')`

Comment: I understand. You don't have the control on the format parameters. But you edited your question afterwards. format can `getattr` but it's very limited. Ex: you cannot slice and you cannot use negative indexes, at least not in python 3.4. For instance, something like this works `{pathname[4]:>90}` but `{pathname[:-10]:>90}` doesn't! bummer. this remains a good question.

Comment: @v217 better late than never. I think my edit could solve your issue.