# f-string behaves differently then the format method for nested formatting

Tags: python, string-formatting, python-3.6, f-string

I am doing nested formatting using `format` and it doesn't work as expected.
however if i try to do it with f-strings it works perfectly.

example:

doing this:

```
values = 'first', 'second', 'third'
a = f"""cardinality and values: {'|'.join(f'val:{val}, card:{i}'for i, val in enumerate(values))} """
```

gives me this (the needed result):

```
'cardinality and values: val:first, card:0|val:scond, card:1|val:third, card:2'
```

however if i try to do it using `format`:

```
a = """cardinality  and values: {'|'.join('val:{val}, card:{i}'.format(val=val, i=i) for i, val in enumerate(values))} """.format(values=values)
```

I get the following exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: "'|'"
```

how do i do this with `format` ?

I need to use `format` instead of f-strings because another file imports this string and then formats it.

Comment: If you pass this as a static string, you won't be able to use it in an `f-string` without something like `eval` which is dangerous.

Comment: format looks for `{}`, and you have thousands of `{}` in your string. Get the logic out of the string and just keep the `{}` to be substituted

Comment: Side note, why use `"""` for a single line string?

Comment: originally it was several lines, forgot to change it to `"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`format` is just less powerful than f-strings, so you have to simplify the format string.

Just get the comprehension from outside the format string:

```
a = "cardinality  and values: {} ".format('|'.join('val:{val}, card:{i}'.format(val=val, i=i) for i, val in enumerate(values)))
```

result:

```
cardinality  and values: val:first, card:0|val:second, card:1|val:third, card:2
```

If you want to make a one-line "template", you could use a `lambda`:

```
a = lambda v : "cardinality  and values: {} ".format('|'.join('val:{val}, card:{i}'.format(val=val, i=i) for i, val in enumerate(v)))
```

now calling

```
print(a(values))
```

invokes the `lambda` which performs the formatting with the passed `values`. That's the closest to f-strings without f-strings that I can think of.

Comment: I want the string to be "plug and play". 
I can use a function and to do what you suggested, but i was wondering if i can do it with format (because it works so well with f-strings).

Comment: yes, but the logic is outside of the string. every time that I will import this string I will have to construct the generator expression again. using a function will solve this problem but this is not the nature of my question.

Comment: maybe creating a subclass of `str` to be able to redefine format as I did here? https://stackoverflow.com/a/48560618/6451573, or a `lambda`

Comment: @moshevi yes, you cannot put arbitrary expressions in the formatting to be used with `format`, that only works with f-strings. This is one of their main advantages. However, you should put these complex exprest anyway, stick to simple straightforward things in f-strings

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible, since you still have `{...}` in the second string `a` and you don't want to use `eval(...)`.

Put the code into `format(...)`?

```
a = """cardinality  and values: {}""".format('|'.join('val:{val}, card:{i}'.format(val=val, i=i) for i, val in enumerate(values)))
```