# Truncate and round all elements of a list to 8 characters

Tags: python

I need to truncate / round / justify all the elements of a list to 8 characters. The input list can contain int (that are never too long), str (that I can truncate) and floats as `float` `float64` or `str`.

Below is a sample of my code :

```py
data = [12452, "too much characters", 0.12457544512, -0.12457544512, "-1245154.8"]
processedData = []

for d in data:
    processedValue = str(d)
    if len(processedValue) > 8 and '.' in processedValue:
        decIndex = processedValue.index(".")
        processedValue = str(round(float(processedValue), 8 - (decIndex + 1)))
    elif len(processedValue) > 8:
        processedValue = processedValue[:8]

    processedData.append(processedValue.rjust(8, " "))

print(processedData)
```

The output and desired output :

```py
['   12452', 'too much', '0.124575', '-0.12458', '-1245150.0'] # Output
['   12452', 'too much', '0.124575', '-0.12458', '-1245155'] # Desired Output
```

When the decimal is near the end of the 8 characters, my values are not rounded at the correct index. When I replace the `elif` condition by `if`, the length is correct but the last digit is still wrong. I've tried some other changes ending up in introducing errors for the other values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use **f-strings** for string formatting.
As the other [user already answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71250405/5730279) check for the type:

- using `isinstance()` builtin function
- a custom defined function `is_float(s)` that returns `True` if value or string can be converted to float (without exception).

Then you can left-pad to a fixed-width string of 8 characters with the *format literal* `:8`  and even round-up to an integer representation with 0 decimal places using `:.0f`. Or use both combined: `:8.0f` - all inside the curly-braces appended to the expression to format (here: `d` or converted `float(d)`):

`f"{float(d):8.0f}" if isinstance(d, float) or is_float(d) else f"{d:8}"`

Including a bit debug-prints at the beginning:

```py
import math
data = [12452, "too much characters", 0.12457544512, -0.12457544512, "-1245154.8"]
print(f"input: {data}")
print(f"dt: {[type(d) for d in data]}")
def is_float(s):
    try:
        float(s)
    except ValueError:
        return False
    return True


processedData = []
for d in data:
    processedValue =  f"{float(d):8.0f}" if isinstance(d, float) or is_float(d) else f"{d:8}"
    print(processedValue)
    if len(processedValue) > 8 and '.' in processedValue:
        decIndex = processedValue.index(".")
        processedValue = str(round(float(processedValue), 8 - (decIndex + 1)))
    elif len(processedValue) > 8:
        processedValue = processedValue[:8]
    processedData.append(processedValue.rjust(8, " "))

print(f"output: {processedData}")
```

Prints as final line the expected:

```
input: [12452, 'too much characters', 0.12457544512, -0.12457544512, '-1245154.8']
dt: [<class 'int'>, <class 'str'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'float'>, <class 'str'>]
   12452
too much characters
       0
      -0
-1245155
output: ['   12452', 'too much', '       0', '      -0', '-1245155']
```

See also:

- [How to truncate a string using str.format in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24076297/how-to-truncate-a-string-using-str-format-in-python)

Comment: Thank you, I guess the `is_float()` function is somehow what I was looking for, allowing to test equally `float` `float64` and `str` containing a float.

Comment: This is very smart, would not have thought of that.

Answer (score 1):

I guess this is one way to fix it with the current data. Results may vary depending on the input.

```
data = [12452, "too much characters", 0.12457544512, -0.12457544512, "-1245154.8"]
processedData = []

for entry in data:
    try:
        entry = float(entry)
    except ValueError:
        pass
    if isinstance(entry, float):
        rounded = round(entry)
        if rounded == 0:
            entry = round(entry,8-(str(entry).index(".")+1))
        else:
            entry = rounded
    entry = str(entry)[:8]
    processedData.append(entry.rjust(8, " "))

print(processedData)
```

Result:

```
['   12452', 'too much', '0.124575', '-0.12458', '-1245155']
```